# Showing the figure window with octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I am a very newbie to octave.

I want to show the figure I plot with octave, but no figure window shows up.

Here is what I want to plot, plot.m

```
x = load('ex2x.dat');
y = load('ex2y.dat');
figure % open a new figure window
plot(x, y, 'o');
ylabel('Height in meters')
xlabel('Age in years')
```

I run the script with the command line directly

```
octave plot.m
```

The dataset can be downloaded from http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=DeepLearning&doc=exercises/ex2/ex2.html

I have installed image package as the site suggested.

My OS is ubuntu 14.04, I am not sure if I miss something.

I appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: It may be something wrong with the graphics renderer. Can you confirm which graphics renderer you are choosing in Octave? Type in `available_graphics_toolkits` in the Octave command window.  Which ones are available? Also, what is currently loaded as the renderer? Type in: `loaded_graphics_toolkits` after you run the `plot` function and see what you get.

Comment: I type `available_graphics_toolkits` in `octave-cli` , and it shows `ans =
{
  [1,1] = fltk
}`

Comment: And I type `loaded_graphics_toolkits`, it shows `ans = {}(1x0)`.

Comment: So it seems no render has been loaded? If so, how do I enforce to load the render?

Comment: Try: `graphics_toolkit("fltk")` then try the plotting code again.

Comment: I add `graphics_toolkit("fltk")` in the first line of `plot.m`, but it still does not work.

Comment: and the output is `warning: function ./plot.m shadows a core library function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer which can be found in Octave's FAQ.

http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ

```
If you are running an Octave script that includes a plotting command,
the script and Octave may terminate immediately. So the plot window
does show up, but immediately closes when Octave finishes execution.
Alternatively, if using fltk, the plot window needs a readline loop to
show up (the time when Octave is sitting around doing nothing waiting for interactive input).
A common solution is to put a pause command at the end of your script.
```

So I just to add `pause` in the end of my script and it shows the window.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @user3378223: Or add --persist